# How to wait for promises resolution instead of using Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, wait

I have a situation where I'm looping over some data and I need to perform an asynchronous operation per each array element. I don't want to await the result inside the loop. Instead I want to simply start off the promises execution from the loop. After the loop is done I want to wait until all promises resolved and then return some result.

The code is below:

```
const t1 = delay => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('from t1')
    resolve()
  }, delay)
})


const promises = []
const results = []
const array = [1 ,2]
array.forEach((element, index) => {
  const temp = t1((index + 1) * 1000).then(() => results.push(5))
  promises.push(temp)
})

const mainFunc = async () => {
  const bigPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    if (results.length === 2) {
      resolve()
    }
  })

  await bigPromise()
  console.log(results)
}

mainFunc()
```

I thought I could create another promise `bigPromise` which will check if the array length is `2`. This way I will know that all promises resolved. However this doesn't work. How can I wait for some notification in Javascript? I wouldn't want to use `setInterval` for this problem.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Promise.all`? `Promise.all(promises)` would be exactly the right tool for the job here

Comment: @CertainPerformance because if I use `Promise.all` then I wouldn't be able to start them off from inside the loop. So I will have to wait until the loop finished and won't be able to save time

Comment: Sure you can - once you've pushed each Promise to `promises`, they've started off, and then with `Promise.all(promises)` you'll have a Promise that resolves when each has resolved

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. What do you mean by *"save time"*? My guess is you misunderstand the exection flow when using Promise.all

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're right, I thought we needed `then` in order to trigger promise execution and it's not the case.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Is there another language primitive that polls the value of something and then returns when the value is equal to something? Maybe I could use generators for this?

Comment: @hitchhiker No, you're indeed misunderstanding promises. There is no polling involved (in JavaScript). You eagerly start the execution of your asynchronous task, and that's what's causing it to run. The promise is just an observable that you can use to be notified about the asynchronous result. Then `Promise.all` builds another promise that lets you observe when all the promises in the input array are fulfilled.